# mysql_fetch_array results from inside another function wont work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two files here and have some problems getting mysql_fetch_array to work.
I think this is because it is called from another function?

show_results.php:

```
include "sql_functions.php";

function content_humanResAll (){
    q_humanResAll();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q_humanResAll_result)){
            ...
```

sql_functions.php:

```
include "db_connect.php"; //connect to db

// Query for human resources
function q_humanResAll() {

    $q_humanResAll = "SELECT * FROM human_resources LIMIT 0, 30";
    $q_humanResAll_result = mysql_query($q_humanResAll) or die("could not query MySql");
    $q_humanResAll_numRows = mysql_num_rows($q_humanResAll_result);
    //return $q_humanResAll_result// tried this also, didn't work.
}
```

Why do I get the error "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given"?

Btw, show_results.php is included in index.php. So its many includes, but it shouldn't be a problem right?

I have also tried making the variables inside function q_humanResAll() global, didn't work either.

Let me know if you need more input.

Thanks

Comment: `mysql_error()` will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: You need to read up on variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Why people downvoting this question? There's a difference between not knowing and not trying (a.k.a ignorant).

Answer (score 1):

You're not defining $q_humanResAll_result in content_humanResAll. So you need to pass it back from the other function, like this:

```
function q_humanResAll() {
    $q_humanResAll = "SELECT * FROM human_resources LIMIT 0, 30";
    $q_humanResAll_result = mysql_query($q_humanResAll) or die("could not query MySql");
    $q_humanResAll_numRows = mysql_num_rows($q_humanResAll_result);
    return $q_humanResAll_result;
}


function content_humanResAll (){
    $q_humanResAll_result = q_humanResAll();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q_humanResAll_result)){
            ...
```